# a coin tossing problem

Tags: probability

A and B are playing coin tossing games. If there is a 2 continuous heads, then A win. If there is a 3 continuous tails, then B win. They keep tossing the coin until one of them win. what's the probability of A wins the game?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

For A to win, it needs to get $2H$ before B gets $3T$.

So, possible cass may be: $$(H,H),(T,H,H), (T,T,H,H)$$
$$P(HH)=\frac{1}{2^2}$$
$$P(THH)=\frac{1}{2^3}$$
$$P(TTHH)=\frac{1}{2^4}$$

There can be more possibilities such as $$(H,T,T,H,H),(T,T,H,T,H,H) \text{ etc. }$$

Try to generalize for $n$ tosses, and then solve for $n\to \infty$

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: This answer is actually for the case where A needs 3 consecutive heads and B needs 4 consecutive tails in order to win. But the same idea works.**

The probability vector $[\mathbb{P}(\text{A wins}), \mathbb{P}(\text{B wins})]$ is given by the average of the first and third row of (matrices typed like when inputted to for example to WolframAlpha)

> { inverse (1/2*[[2,-1,-1,0,0], [0,2,-1,0,0],[-1,0,2,-1,0], [-1,0,0,2,-1], [-1,0,0,0,2]] ) } [[0,0], [1/2,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,1/2]]

and is $[\frac{15}{22}, \frac{7}{22}]$.

In this solution we are calculating the absorption probabilities of a Markov chain with states $H, HH, T, TT, TTT, A, B$ (with obvious meanings and transition probabilities).

Here' how the chain looks like (all transitions have probability $\frac{1}{2}$ except the absorbing winning states $A$ and $B$ of course have self-transition with probability $1$) I included the starting state $S$ here but not in the calculations where this is accounted for by averaging whether you start from $H$ or $T$ (whether the first toss is heads or tails):

[image]

**EDIT:**
For the actual question, the appropriate calculation is (notice: I have left the factors $\frac{1}{2}$ out since they will cancel each other as the first is inverted)

> [[2,-1,-1,0], [0,2,-1,0], [0,-1,2,-1], [0,-1,0,2]]^(-1) * [[0,0], [1,0], [0,0], [0,1]]

which gives $[\frac{7}{10}, \frac{3}{10}]$ in the first row.

Comment: For some reason, WolframAlpha wouldn't show the result correctly if you put the last $\frac{1}{2}$ inside the matrix like I have done above. Take it out and remember to divide by $2$ yourself if this also happens to you, i.e insert  [[0,0], [1,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,1]] instead in the above formula.

Comment: Hi @ploosu2. Could you explain how you worked? Did you construct a matrix $\begin{bmatrix}Q & R\\0& I_s\end{bmatrix}$ where Q is the submatrix containing the transient probabilities with 5 different states (H,HH,T,TT,TTT)? so then you took the fundamental matrix $N=(I-Q)^{-1}$ and multiplied the result by submatrix R where you have the absorbing probabilities for A and B?

Comment: @Marco Yes, that's exactly right.

Comment: is there any other way to do this without matrices? I am trying this approach but it gives a different result ($21/30$): Let $P_n$ be the transition probability for state n. So $P_s=0.5P_h+0.5P_t$ where $P_h$ is the probability of transitioning when we are in the state in which we have observed 1 head. $P_h=0.5P_A+0.5P_t$ where $P_t$ is the state in which we have observed 1 tail. $P_t=0.5P_h+0.5P_t^2$; 


$P_t^2=0.5P_h+0.5P_B$; 

$P_A=1$; 


$P_B=0$ these are the absorbing states. Do you know why I get a different result? what is wrong with it?

Comment: Actually the result of my approach is $\frac{7}{10}$

Comment: @Marco Oh, I see I have made an error. In my diagram A actually needs 3 consecutive heads and B 4 consecutive tails to win. It needs to be modified by actually making the states $HH$ and $TTT$ absorbing states (and dropping the current states A and B). The answer $\frac{7}{10}$ is correct. Thanks for pointing this out.